# invoke causes Cannot access a disposed object

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, forms, delegates

I have a `form` in load page i create a thread and delegate to show a position that every time is updated :

```
   private delegate void UpdateListBoxDelegate();
  private UpdateListBoxDelegate UpdateListBox = null;

private void frmMain_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
             pictureBoxonlineTrain.Parent = pictureBoxMetroMap;
            UpdateListBox = new UpdateListBoxDelegate(this.UpdateStatus);
            // Initialise and start worker thread
            workerThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(this.GetOnlineTrain));
            workerThread.Start();
         }
```

So in my `load form` i called this by thread:

```
   private bool stop = false;
    public void GetOnlineTrain()
    {
        try
        {
            while (stop!=true)
            {
                TimeTableRepository objTimeTableREpository = new TimeTableRepository();
                OnlineTrainList = objTimeTableREpository.GetAll().ToList();
                objTimeTableREpository = null;
                if(stop!=true)
                Invoke(UpdateListBox);
                else this.Dispose();


            }
        }
        catch(Exception a)
        {
        }

    }
```

My problem is when i want to show another form i got this error:

```
        stop = true;
        frmPath frmPath = new frmPath();
        frmPath.ShowDialog();
```

This error

```
  Cannot access a disposed object  -{System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'frmMain'.
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.MarshaledInvoke(Control caller, Delegate method, Object[] args, Boolean synchronous)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method, Object[] args)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.Invoke(Delegate method)
   at PresentationLayer.PreLayer.frmMain.GetOnlineTrain() in d:\TFS Project\Railway\ShirazMetro\PresentationLayer\PreLayer\frmMain.cs:line 167}
```

I got this error in `GetOnlineTrain` method .

I `FrmPath` in `formload` when i put this line i got the above error ,but when i clear this line every thing works fine!!!!!!!

```
private void frmLine_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    txtNumber.Focus();

    gvListLine.DataSource = objLineRepository.GetAll().ToList();
 }
```

Best regards

Comment: To start with stop writing code like this: `catch(Exception a) { }`. It hides your true errors and does nothing to help your program run correctly (i.e. "error-free" is **not** necessarily correct).

Answer (score 1):

Your thread loops endless (because of the `while (true)`).
So once you close your form (I assume when you "want to show another form" you close your old form) and call Dispose on it (probably done by the framework). The thread however will continue working with that form since it will not stop. The next time it calls `Invoke` it will crash.

Comment: @Mehrdad: You need to redesign the `GetOnlineTrain()` method completely provide a "stop" criteria like `while (!Stopped)`. Additionally you need to actually set that flag within the dispose method of the form and you need to wait until the tread exists. (This can lead to various deadlocks if not done correctly. However to line up a complete solution would be too complex)

Comment: I do that as you said ,please take a look the updated post ,but same error .

Comment: 1. `stop` is never set. 2. you don't need to call dispose yourself. 3. the main form needs to wait for the thread to stop WITHIN an override of Dispose().

Comment: @Mehrdad - Please don't **update** your answers on Stack Overflow. You should only edit your questions if there is an issue in the way they are written or to extend the question by adding new information to the bottom. Otherwise you can make it very difficult for other users to understand how the answers fit the question if it changes.

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked for me.

**// THE CODE THAT SOLVED THE CRASH ON EXITING THE FORM**

```
        // Aborts the Thread On Form Close // Stops Crashing on Form CLose 
        protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            if(captureThread.IsAlive)
            {
                captureThread.Abort();
            }

            base.OnClosing(e);
        }
```

**// THE WHOLE FORM**

```
   using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Drawing;
    using System.Drawing.Imaging;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    
    namespace ScreenRecorder1
    {
        public partial class Form1 : Form
        {
            Thread captureThread; // The Thread
    
    
    
            public Form1()
            {
                InitializeComponent();
             
    
            }
    
    
    
    
    
    
            private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {     
                captureThread = new Thread(CaptureScreen);
                captureThread.IsBackground = true;
                captureThread.Start();     
            }
    
    
    
    
    
    
            private void screenshot_bbutton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
            {
                CaptureScreen();
            }
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
            private void CaptureScreen()
            {
               
                while(true)
                {
                       Rectangle screenBounds = Screen.GetBounds(Point.Empty);  // Screen Size
                       Bitmap bmp1 = new Bitmap(screenBounds.Width, screenBounds.Height); // BMP
    
                       Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(bmp1); // Graphics
                       g.CopyFromScreen(Point.Empty, Point.Empty, screenBounds.Size); // Screen To BMP
                  
                  
                       Invoke(new Action(() => { Player_pictureBox.BackgroundImage = bmp1; })); // Display    
    
                       g.Dispose();
                      
                       Thread.Sleep(50);
                      
                }
    
             
                         
            }
    
    
    
    
            // Aborts the Thread On Form Close // Stops Crashing on Form CLose
            protected override void OnClosing(CancelEventArgs e)
            {
                if(captureThread.IsAlive)
                {
                    captureThread.Abort();
                }
    
                base.OnClosing(e);
            }
    
    
    
    
    
    
        }
    
    
    
    
    }
```